# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, urllib

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I have been trying to teach myself how to use BeautifulSoup so that I can create a few projects.

I was following this link as a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzVNi0oTxQ

After following the exact same code as him, this is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1240, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1237, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
_context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WorldCup.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 483, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1283, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1242, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]     certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>
```

Can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: What URL are you trying? Does the host use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: www.google.com, like he did in the video. My code is the same as his.

Comment: I get the same error with any other website that I use, i.e. youtube.com, wikipedia.com etc

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275540/sslerror-certificate-verify-failed-for-every-domain-url

Comment: I got the same error as earlier. It's not working "/ I know it was workinge arlier because I was able to use it on another website.

Answer (score 185):

In my case, I used the `ssl` module to "workaround" the certification like so:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Then to read your link content, you can use:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(urllink)
```

Note that whilst this will make the code *work*, it removes security protections.

Comment: Great solution. Worked and helped me figure out what was going on in the first place.

Comment: worked perfectly well, i couldn't find the "Install Certificates.command", but this solution worked perfectly well for certificate issue.

Comment: NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Comment: @BrianD check your version of Python. `urllib` import path has changed in recent versions of Python.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I wasn't able to find the "Install Certificates.command" file either. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Works with pandas too.

Comment: For a weird reason certificates didn't work for me, but this workaround did the job.

Comment: @Jia I face this error when trying to upload my package to artifactory. Where should I add these two lines since my package has many modules?

Comment: How do I get the page content from `urllib.request.urlopen(urllink)` ? In other words, what is equivalent of `requests.get(MY_URL).content`?

Comment: Worked for me - easy fix.

Answer (score 138):

Go to the folder where Python is installed, e.g., in my case (Mac OS) it is installed in the Applications folder with the folder name 'Python 3.6'. Now double click on 'Install Certificates.command'. You will no longer face this error.

For those not running a mac, or having a different setup and can't find this file, the file merely runs:

`pip install --upgrade certifi`

Comment: What is the significance of the code - what change did it apply  - care to explain ?

Comment: To the people saying they can't find this file - this solution is only Apple products.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also it worked on Python3.7 :)

Comment: This and only this command worked. It installed the right certificates. I have tried numuours and had lost trust with stackoverflwo.

Answer (score 38):

On Debian 9 I had to:

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
$ export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

I'm not sure why, but this enviroment variable was never set.

Comment: Thank you, I faced the same issue on Raspbian Stretch after manually installing Python 3.8, and solved setting that environment variable.

Comment: It might not even be necessary to update certificates - in my case, just exporting the path worked.

Comment: I started having this problem after installing a new pip package. As @Kaja mentioned just exporting the path worked for me as well on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The 2nd line worked on Mac OS Big Sur for me.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu20.04 after Dropbox was failing to install. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks. export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs did the trick on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8):

This has changed in recent versions of the ssl library.  The SSLContext was moved to it's own property.  This is the equivalent of Jia's answer in Python 3.8

```
import ssl

ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode = ssl.VerifyMode.CERT_OPTIONAL
```

Comment: 'SSLContext' object attribute 'verify_mode' is read-only

Comment: Whilst I wish there was a better way than using the [protected member in Jia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174340/866333), your new answer doesn't substitute for it. In python 3.8 I receive: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate`

Comment: I posted this answer because Jia's answer didn't work for me and this did.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a wiki. Instead of writing a new answer that references another answer, you should just edit that other answer to say "if version x, do y, else do z".

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround (not secure), you can turn certificate verification off by setting PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY environment variable to 0:

```
export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a lib what use https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ what use https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ but I have a custom CA included in my `/etc/ssl/certs`.

So I solved my problem like this:

```
# Your TLS certificates directory (Debian like)
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
# CA bundle PATH (Debian like again)
export CA_BUNDLE_PATH="${SSL_CERT_DIR}/ca-certificates.crt"
# If you have a virtualenv:
. ./.venv/bin/activate
# Get the current certifi CA bundle
CERTFI_PATH=`python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())'`

test -L $CERTFI_PATH || rm $CERTFI_PATH
test -L $CERTFI_PATH || ln -s $CA_BUNDLE_PATH $CERTFI_PATH
```

Et voilà !

Comment: Thanks!  This seems like the best solution - I'm using using python 3.11.

Answer (score 4):

Building on the update to [Jia's 2018 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174340/866333) in [deltree's late 2021 one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69724616/866333) I was able to achieve equivalent functionality with:

```py
import urllib.request
import ssl


def urllib_get_2018():
    # Using a protected member like this is not any more fragile
    # than extending the class and using it. I would use it.
    url = 'https://localhost:6667/my-endpoint'
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url = url) as f:
        print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))


def urllib_get_2022():
    # Finally! Able to use the publice API. Happy happy!
    url = 'https://localhost:6667/my-endpoint'
    scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    scontext.verify_mode = ssl.VerifyMode.CERT_NONE
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url = url, context=scontext) as f:
        print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I needed to use `CERT_NONE` instead of `CERT_OPTIONAL` as well as creating a `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)` to pass to `urlopen`.

It's important to keep using `urllib` as it makes sense when working with small container images where `pip` might not be installed, yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a self signed cert urllib3 version 1.25.3 refuses to ignore the SSL cert

To fix remove urllib3-1.25.3 and install urllib3-1.24.3

`pip3 uninstall urllib3`

`pip3 install urllib3==1.24.3`

Tested on Linux MacOS and Window$

Comment: i tried this but it did not work for me (still getting the same error). In my case I think the certificates are valid but are not being used.

Comment: If your target has a valid certificate you don't need this fix.
To check if you site has a valid certificate run:
`curl https://target.web.site/`
If you get a message "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate" you have a self signed certificate on your target.
If you get a proper answer from the site then the certificate is valid.

Comment: Yeah the error I'm seeing is that my local machine's certificates are not being used. The target's certificates are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Ubuntu 20.4 and have tried many solutions but nothing worked out. Finally I just checked openssl version. Even after update and upgrade, the openssl version showed **OpenSSL 1.1.1h [22 Sep 2020]**. But in my windows system, where the code works without any issue, openssl version is **OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021**.

I decided to update the openssl manually and it worked! Thank God!!!

Steps are as follows(Ubuntu 20.4):

*To check openssl version

```
openssl version -a
```

*To update openssl:

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall zlib1g-dev

cd /usr/local/src/

sudo wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz

sudo tar -xf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz

cd openssl-1.1.1k

sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib
sudo make
sudo make test
sudo make install

cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
sudo nano openssl-1.1.1k.conf
```

*Type /usr/local/ssl/lib and save

```
sudo ldconfig -v
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

*Add ':/usr/local/ssl/bin' to the path

```
source /etc/environment
echo $PATH
```

*Now check openssl version

```
openssl version -a
```

Answer (score 0):

you might exec command: `pip install --upgrade certifi`
or you might opened charles/fiddler, just close it

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem in MacOS, and I solved it by linking the brew installed python 3 version, with

```
brew link python3
```

After that, it worked without a problem.

Comment: While just installing python3 via Brew may resolve this issue, it does not address the root cause. FYI for anyone checking out this answer.