# Biopython Entrez error in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, biopython

I am new to using Pycharm. I am trying to access Entrez databases using the Bio.Entrez module in Pycharm and get an error message regardless of which Bio.Entrez function I use:

```
from Bio import Entrez
handle = Entrez.einfo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
_context=self, _session=session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 283, in einfo
return _open(cgi, variables)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 524, in _open
handle = _urlopen(cgi)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

Strangely, it works in Anaconda Spyder, but I prefer PyCharm and would like to figure this out.

Comment: The error is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35569042 Maybe you can find solution there.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Biopython, but is a more general problem Python with the SSL certificates and (I think) openssl.

How to fix this will depend on how your Python was compiled/installed, and your operating system.