# Working behind company's SAML and getting cerficate verification failed

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, saml

My company recently implemented SAML and causing my python app not able to verify the certificate. Keep showing error "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)" Is there any workaround for this issue?

I have tried installing certifi but it is still not working.

Comment: I have no idea what this has to do with SAML and you show no code which produces this error. In general you need to have the CA which is issuing the certificates in your trust store. `certifi` does this only for the common public CA. For private CA you might have in your company you have to do this by your own. The details on how this is done depend on the specific use case where TLS is used - which is not provided in your question (i.e. too broad).

Comment: Another StackOverflow question [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569042/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-python3) provides two resolutions on SSL certificate issue of Python3.