# Python discord bot spits out traceback error

Tags: discord

I am trying to make a discord bot for my server using python but I have run into a Traceback error and I am unsure of how to fix it.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="minted ")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("we ready boiis")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Error: https://pastebin.pl/view/812d718d

Comment: Try running `pip install --upgrade certifi`.  If that doesn't work, you can try more of the proposed solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569042/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-python3

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately it didn't work.