# Getting [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error in python while trying requests.post over https

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

Python Version: 3.6

OS: CentOS 7

Python Code

```
import requests
import json
import logging

proxies = {
    "http": None,
    "https": None,
}

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "accept": "application/json"
}

auth = {
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
}

resp = requests.post("https://192.168.99.2:8002/login", headers=headers, proxies=proxies, json=auth)
resp_json = json.loads(resp.content)
logging.info("Response = {}".format(resp_json))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 426, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 773, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1033, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 645, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 450, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 786, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.99.2', port=8002): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 20, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    resp = requests.post("https://192.168.99.2:8002/login", headers=headers, proxies=proxies, json=auth)                                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post                                                                                                                                                           
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request                                                                                                                                                         
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request                                                                                                                                                   
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.99.2', port=8002): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
```

Process Info:

I have a IoT product KVM (supporting Rest API calls over port 8002 and ip=192.168.99.2) running on same system. I am trying to communicate with the KVM but I am getting this certificate verify failed. I am not sure what is causing this.

When I try normal CURL commands, I am able to successfully communicate with the KVM.

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://192.168.99.2:8002/gateway_ca.crt

$ curl --cacert gateway_ca.crt -X POST "https://192.168.99.2:8002/login" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\"}"

{"failed_login_attempts":0,"last_login_host":"192.168.99.1","last_login_time":"{\"sec\": 1663328807 , \"nsec\": 149641000 }","message":"","must_change_password":true,"sessions_limit_exceeded":false,"token":"bhD1eagDOpbOkDLpLOD29K3L"}
```

What has been tried out?

1. I have tried adding the gateway_ca.crt in trusted root certificates using following commands:

```
$ sudo cp gateway_ca.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

$ sudo  update-ca-trust extract
```

2. Tried passing verify='/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem' as an argument to requests.post call but still facing same issue.
3. Donwoloaded gateway_ca.crt and passed it as verify='path-to-gateway_ca.crt' in requests.post call but still facing same error
4. Tried appending contents of gateway_ca.crt to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem but still system complains of certificate issues.
5. Tried sourcing REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt' but it didn't help.

Kindly guide me on what restrictions on python side might be causing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED with Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569042/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-python3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests - How to use system ca-certificates (debian/ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: @Kelo, Thanks for the suggestion but the listed answers didn't help me.

Comment: @SitiSchu Thanks for the recommended thread and I tried out suggestions posted there but still observing same failure.