# Unexpected EOF while reading when using requests in python. EOF occurred in violation of protocol _ssl.c:1007

Tags: python, ssl

Trying to run this script (some information edited out for data sharing restrictions). I'm running it from a databricks notebook using python 3.10 and trying to use a Collibra REST API. The below statement works fine if I run it from a desktop version of python but running into this issue on databricks.

`requests.get(https://organisationName.collibra.com/rest/2.0/assets/1230b974-4c83-4f22-88a7-11c5e1ty1234, headers=headers, verify = False)`

I get this error:

> *SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='organisationName.collibra.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/2.0/assets/1230b974-4c83-4f22-88a7-11c5e1ty1234 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))*

Also tried the above without setting verify to False and had the same issue. The headers only contain an authorisation parameter and nothing else. The requests package version is 2.28.1.

I went through other related posts and tried installing/updating packages like ndg-httpsclient, pyopenssl but didn't help me.
I'm not sure how to resolve this or who in my org I should be reaching out to. I'm relatively new at this.

Comment: What are the values for `ssl.HAS_TLSv1`, `ssl.HAS_TLSv1_1`, `ssl.HAS_TLSv1_2`,  and `ssl.HAS_TLSv1_3` in the databricks environment?

Comment: The URL has to be a string, so that isn't your code.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with the OpenSSL 3. I believe you are using a Linux OS which come with openssl 3. In my case it was Ubuntu 22.04 which comes with OpenSSL 3.

You can find the explanation here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-22-stack#openssl-3
Similar bug reports on other software stack but related : https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/10915

Few of the Possbile Solutions :

1. Install OpenSSL 1.x & recompiling python to use OpenSSL 1.x
2. Install Python 3.8 which afaik uses OpenSSL 1.x by default.
3. Containerize your application so it uses a Python base image which uses OpenSSL 1.x.

In my case I chose (3) and issue is resolved. I used python:3.8.13-alpine3.16 as a base image.

> Note : Don't use python:3.8.13-alpine3.17 or higher as starting from alpine3.17 it uses OpenSSL 3.

Comment: The problem is not OpenSSL 3 - the problem is the outdated, insecure crypto schemes used by the sites are no longer supported in newer versions of OpenSSL.