# "SSL certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain" when pip install

Tags: python, ssl, pip, self-signed

I'm behind a company proxy with a self-signed certificate and I want to install `tensorstore` via `pip`. `pip` apparently downloads and runs a Python script `bazelisk.py` that in turn uses `urllib` to get more stuff from the Internet. However, this fails with a `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error message:

```
$ pip install --trusted-host=example.com --index-url=http://example.com/pypi/simple
...
  Downloading https://releases.bazel.build/6.4.0/release/bazel-6.4.0-linux-arm64...
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
      h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1285, in request
      self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
      self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 980, in send
      self.connect()
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
      self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
      return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
      self.do_handshake()
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ycop_psv/tensorstore_1008eee73d464825b2e191c044b9e306/bazelisk.py", line 492, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ycop_psv/tensorstore_1008eee73d464825b2e191c044b9e306/bazelisk.py", line 477, in main
      bazel_path = get_bazel_path()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ycop_psv/tensorstore_1008eee73d464825b2e191c044b9e306/bazelisk.py", line 470, in get_bazel_path
      return download_bazel_into_directory(bazel_version, is_commit, bazel_directory)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ycop_psv/tensorstore_1008eee73d464825b2e191c044b9e306/bazelisk.py", line 304, in download_bazel_into_directory
      download(bazel_url, destination_path)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ycop_psv/tensorstore_1008eee73d464825b2e191c044b9e306/bazelisk.py", line 353, in download
      with closing(urlopen(request)) as response, open(destination_path, "wb") as file:
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
      response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
      result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
      return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
    File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
      raise URLError(err)
  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)>
  error: command '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/PyTorch-1.11.0/bin/python3.9' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensorstore
Failed to build tensorstore
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tensorstore which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I already know this error message from software such as Huggingface, and managed to solve it in many cases.

I already put the required company certificates to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` and run `update-ca-trust` afterwards (Note: I'm on a CentOS-derived distro). By verifying the timestamps and contents of `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem`, I made sure the update was successful. `curl https://www.google.com` works. But `pip install` still fails.

So, I [`pip install certifi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855394), and retried. Still fails. `certifi` actually installs the certificates from `requests`, which naturally don't include our company's self-signed certificates. So, I replaced certifi's PEM file with a link to above-mentioned `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem`:

```
mv "$(python -m certifi)"{,.bak}
ln -s "/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem" "$(python -m certifi)"
```

But this changes nothing. `pip install tensorstore` still fails with above-mentioned error.

Setting [`REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717517) doesn't work here, because `requests` is not involved.

At this point, I'm don't know further. Any solution presented to me online only revolves around the solutions I already mentioned. Not even a quick-and-dirty [`verify=False` equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445989), [PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71380824), or [unverified SSL context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174340) could be applied to my current situation because the script run is temporary, downloaded every time I try to install.

So, how could I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `SSL_CERT_FILE` successfully managed to guide Python's `urllib` to the correct PEM file:

```
$ export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
$ pip install --trusted-host=example.com --index-url=http://example.com/pypi/simple tensorstore
```

But now, another, possibly unrelated problem occurred. SSL certificate problem in Java...

Answer (score 1):

For Java you can simply add your pem file into the truststore of your JDK using keytool:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias serveralias -file /Applications/certificate.pem -keystore /cacerts
```

Comment: Exactly, but the tricky part was to figure out which keystore bazel was using. In this case, it was a temporary keystore somewhere in `/tmp`, different from my system's Java installation. The [solution](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10349#issuecomment-797404643) then was to make bazel use my system's keystore: `echo "startup --host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/java/cacerts --host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" >> ~/.bazelrc`