# Python requests() package has many errors I cant resolve

Tags: python, python-requests

I use pycharm for python (v3.2) AND I want to use the Requests package for some API stuff. I downloaded the requests package from PyPi.org (v2.31) and used pip command to install package into my working project. I use a simple import command in my python module and try to read some data from an API website as follows:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

I then get the following long line of errors.. help??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 782, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 514, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 1046, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 1317, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfischer\PycharmProjects\NewProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I expected it to work like any example I have seen

Comment: Have you consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35569042/6394617) post?